# Confusion with Algorithm for n + (n-1) + (n-2)

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to expand this answer in iteration after using recursion but i am getting the wrong answer for certain variables.

the question was to write a code for n + (n-1) + (n-2)... till it gets to 3 + 2 + 1

i did it with recursion and it works great but the iteration is the one giving me problem.

this is what i tried in java.

```
for (int i =1; i <num; i ++) {
  s += n -1;
  }
  return s;
```

where n is the user inputed varibale, and s is some kind of sum variable.
Also please can you explain what the s+=n -1 means?

i am finding it hard to place it right now. Please and Thank you!

Also i tried to put it <= num
and return s-1; but it did not work either

Comment: `n` never changes. Remove the `i`, loop until `n` is `<= 0`.

Comment: `s += anything` is the same as `s = s + anything`. So `s += n - 1` is the same as `s = s + (n - 1)`.

Comment: Why subtract `1` from n everytime? Where are you ever getting `(n-2)`? What is `num`?

Comment: You say you tried it with recursion, but the code example you posted really doesn't use recursion

Comment: Start with n and loop till it gets to 1. `for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) { s += i; }`

Comment: `int s = (n*(n+1))/2;` math (Gauss).

Comment: is the for loop in your question your actual code ? because in the *for* you use ```num``` and ```n``` one line below, so it would not even compile.

Comment: *"s is some kind of sum variable"*: what do you mean with "some kind"? Can't you just define it in code unambiguously? What is `num`? What is `n`?

Answer (score 2):

To do *exactly* as you described, you can do it like this.

```
int sum = 0;
int n = 100;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   sum += n-i; // first n, then n-1, then n-2, ...
}
```

But that is the same as the following, only in reversed order.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
   sum += i;
}
```

and as stated in the comments, the arithmetic series sum where the difference between adjacent values is 1,  for any value n, is

```
sum = (n*(n+1))/2;
```

All the above yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code, you are not even adding the right thing to the `s`

- you add `n-1` but that doesn't even contain your iteration variable `i` and also, you are iterating to `num`, not 'n' - you should be adding `num-i`
- also, check what your `s` initially is, if you got `int s = num;` somewhere above, it's ok. But, if you got `int s = 0;`, you will have to either change it to `num` or start at `i = 0` instead

Comment: Lol thank you. I didn’t want to give my exact code in case my professor sees this by some chance.   But on my own code , I did add the num to the sun. It is sum += num-1

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it exactly as it's stated: we should loop over `n, n - 1, n - 2, ..., 3, 2, 1`, so we

- start looping from `n`: `int i = n`
- loop up and including `1`: `i >= 1`
- decrement loop valitable (let it be `i`) by `1`: `--i`

We are ready to write `for` loop caption:

```
for (int i = n; i >= 1; --i)
```

And the code can be

```
int n = 100;

int s = 0;

for (int i = n; i >= 1; --i)
    s = sum + i;
```

If we want to wrap it into method:

```
static int MySum(int n) {
  int s = 0;

  for (int i = n; i >= 1; --i)
    s = sum + i; 

  return s;
}
```